# Working with *lots* of columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to add 144 columns to an entity, but I don't want to write 144 properties. Can I create columns (via code-first) and access them (query them) in a loop?

Comment: This sounds like a good time for a T4 solution.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel What's a T4 solution?

Comment: If you're using code first, you might want to try the EF Power Tools and reverse engineer your models from the DB. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: 144 columns/properties is a hint that something is very wrong.

Comment: @MikeSW I want to store a 144-dimensional vector and I need to search on it. AFAIK there are no data types for this purpose, so I have to make them separate columns, no?

Comment: OK, but here is what i get by Google search http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/06/14/187/c6a/643bcfb6eac4a023e45ed0e4913974ccdcbeea6f.png

Comment: @HamletHakobyan That's wonderful. Google search results are customized to the user. Just because it's the top hit in your results, doesn't mean it's the top hit in mine. Please don't make assumptions about whether or not I put in any effort. (For the record, I *did* search before I asked)

Answer (score 1):

With T4 templates you can create C# with a script. For more information about this topic you may visit this page:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx